# MusicBrainz web service on Ruby on Rails wrapper questions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wrapper

I am trying to use the following music wrapper

https://github.com/localhots/musicbrainz

The readme is too minimalist for me and I am not sure how to use this service wrapper. First, the readme mentions the following information on configuration

```
MusicBrainz.configure do |c|
  # Application identity (required)
  c.app_name = "My Music App"
  c.app_version = "1.0"
  c.contact = "support@mymusicapp.com"

  # Cache config (optional)
  c.cache_path = "/tmp/musicbrainz-cache"
  c.perform_caching = true

  # Querying config (optional)
  c.query_interval = 1.2 # seconds
  c.tries_limit = 2
end
```

Where should I put this information? In a separate file under the config folder? Should I copy paste it somewhere in some of my config files (environment.rb?).

Once the configuration is done. Do I have access to all methods presented in the readme? I tried the example:

```
@suggestions = MusicBrainz::Artist.search("Jet")
```

But it return a hash, not an object

```
[{:name=>"Jec", :sort_name=>"Jec", :weight=>0, :desc=>nil, :type=>nil, :mbid=>"a8e34279-511f-4d8b-b40e-be503faec482"}, {:name=>"JDT", :sort_name=>"JDT", :weight=>0, :desc=>nil, :type=>"Group", :mbid=>"f10c42bc-0679-46ea-ac3d-2b446088c659"}, {:name=>"Jat", :sort_name=>"Jat", :weight=>0, :desc=>nil, :type=>"Group", :mbid=>"9b00250c-0d4d-4bdc-bd8c-37ca6cef8707"}, {:name=>"Jeti", :sort_name=>"Jeti", :weight=>0, :desc=>nil, :type=>"Group", :mbid=>"0076ec01-5abb-4904-97c6-643b4bf58fd5"}, {:name=>"JeV", :sort_name=>"JeV", :weight=>0, :desc=>nil, :type=>nil, :mbid=>"238e1ea2-f267-47f3-9f24-9a55e312b05a"}, {:name=>"Jei", :sort_name=>"Jei", :weight=>0, :desc=>nil, :type=>nil, :mbid=>"ddb7dde4-2cf1-43b2-95a6-bb60adcd52de"}, {:name=>"Jeto", :sort_name=>"Jeto", :weight=>0, :desc=>nil, :type=>nil, :mbid=>"bef1576f-6db7-473b-8fbf-359326bf48e0"}, {:name=>"Jest", :sort_name=>"Jest", :weight=>0, :desc=>nil, :type=>nil, :mbid=>"ba3e36b1-21c7-466e-83fa-fef43e2b9731"}, {:name=>"DJet", :sort_name=>"DJet", :weight=>0, :desc=>nil, :type=>nil, :mbid=>"174961e4-2ccb-4c66-aa2d-d86ab244cfc5"}, {:name=>"Jek", :sort_name=>"Jek", :weight=>0, :desc=>nil, :type=>"Person", :mbid=>"900a8e05-ff80-4f8d-a559-98368ed7d5a3"}]
```

and I am not sure what to with this. Could anyone give me more guidance on how to use this resource? Thanks.

Comment: That's an array of hashes, one for each artist. It looks like each hash has a `:name` element for the artist's name and an `:mbid` element which can be used to perform further queries, as in the README: `@kasabian = MusicBrainz::Artist.find("69b39eab-6577-46a4-a9f5-817839092033")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put it anywhere you want, just before you use it (probably not the best place) or on a initializer (go ahead and try this path first)

Yeah, most API wrappers return a Hash or a object wrapping a Hash, that's because they are simply translating JSON (or XML) to Ruby. BTW, what you got is an array of hashes, loop through them and you will have the information you need:

```
@suggestions.each do |suggestion|
  puts suggestion[:name]
end
```

What you do with it is up to yo.

Comment: What would be the appropriate syntax if I want to put this in a view template? This does not seem to work:
<% @suggestions.each do |suggestion| %>
<% suggestion[:name] %>
<% end %>

Comment: How it doesn't work? Perhaps you are missing the `<%=` so the name is not being printed? Also try a debugger (prybug, for example) and tell me what value @suggestions hold, what about suggestion when inside the loop?